# RVM does not respond to any actions

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Hoping for some help here, as I'm pretty stuck on this one.

I encountered an issue today where RVM has stopping responding to 
actions. My OS is Lion and my RVM installation had worked very well 
for months. I can't think of any recent system changes that could have 
possibly borked my RVM installation.

Issuing `rvm` returns exactly what you'd expect: http://cl.ly/3V0M3k1k13453Z0B0M1j

However, is I use any RVM action, it just hangs there forever.

Example: `rvm list`
Example: `rvm install 1.9.3`
http://cl.ly/3R2b3H3u223I2E1v101j

The only way to proceed is to interrupt the command by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

So far, I've uninstalled RVM by hand and successfully reinstalled. The 
results are the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not post information on external sites, and do not post images when text would suffice.

Comment: This is not an "answer" but if you are stuck you might want to try rbenv - https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv - as this may help you get past your current issue (or perhaps help diagnose exactly what the issue is).

Comment: are you using ZSH? any fancy shell aliases, do you control your *rc files or just pull from someones else repo?

Comment: Please check whether your user account is in the group "rvm". By default, your user account ,even the "root" account, is not automatically in the group .
I discovered the solution and solved the similar problem by reading the hints of "rvm notes"/

Answer (score 1):

The things to check are:

1. Your env PATH entry using `echo $PATH`. Does that look sane for your environment? RVM's entries should be first or second in the chain.
2. What does `which rvm` show? Does that make sense in your environment and for the type of RVM installation you did? A standard RVM would be in `~/.rvm`.
3. What does `rvm info` say and does that look sane for your environment?

With that information we can provide better answers to you, and you can look through the diagnostics on [RVM's installation page](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) and compare your output to what you should see.

---

This is the output of a fresh install of RVM and Ruby 1.9.3 on my machine:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin Greg.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.13.8 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "12 minutes 39 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p194"
    date:         "2012-04-20"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin10.8.0"
    patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35410"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    ruby:         "/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/greg/.rvm/bin:/Users/greg/.pythonbrew/bin:/Users/greg/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/bin:/Users/greg/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/Users/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: To me, all of these look correct:
1. **$ echo $PATH**
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

2. **$ which rvm** : /Users/username/.rvm/bin/rvm

3. **$ rvm info** : just hangs as previously described.

Comment: I just added the output of a fresh install of RVM's `rvm info` on my machine for your comparison. If your settings appear to match I'd send a note to RVM's author at http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm